# Generate ordered pairs from a set/list, in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, set

I'd like to generate ordered pairs from a list/set of items in NodeJS

Example: I have a list/set with items : [a, b, c]

Generate the ordered pairs: (a,b) , (a,c) , (b,a) , (b,c) , (c,a) , (c,b)

How can I easily do this in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is JavaScript, so here is a method :

```
var _set = ['a','b','c'];
var _pairs = [];
for (var i=0; i<_set.length; i++){
        var selectedNow = _set[i];
    for (var j=0; j<_set.length;j++){
       if(selectedNow == _set[j]){/*ignore*/}
       else{
            var combination = selectedNow + _set[j];
          _pairs.push(combination);
       }
    }
}
console.log(_pairs);
```

In this example, the console will print the following array :

```
[ "ab", "ac", "ba", "bc", "ca", "cb" ]
```

A working fiddle example, if you want to play around with it :
https://jsfiddle.net/hap2jfy4/

Comment: Thanks! This works although I thought there might be something like Python's itertools

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = [a, b, c];

var pairs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            continue;
        }
        pairs.push([
          list[i],
          list[j]
        ]);
    }
    pairs.push(pair);
}
```

Results in an array of pair-arrays, therefor pairs[0] is your array of (a, b).

- pairs[0][0] being a
- pairs[0][1] being b

Answer (score 1):

a bit less bulky:

```
let set = ["a", "b", "c"];
let pairs = [];
set.forEach(function(x){
    set.forEach(function(y) {
        if (x !== y) {
            pairs.push([x,y])
        }
    })
})
```